# How to print, sort and get temps above 90

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, printing

```
Place code to print elements from arr_param
Place code to sort elements in arr_param in ascending order of fahrenheit temperature
Place code to print out elements from arr_param with temperatures > 90 deg. F

There is a private class to do the conversions from F to C to K. 
public class Temperature {
   public Temperature(double p_fahren) {
      fahrenTemp = p_fahren;
   }
   public void setFahrenheit(double p_fahren) {
      fahrenTemp = p_fahren;
   }
   public double getFahrenheit() {
      return fahrenTemp;
   }
   public double getCelsius() {
      double celsius_temp;
      celsius_temp = (5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenTemp - 32.0);
      return celsius_temp;
   }
   public double getKelvin() {
      double kelvin_temp = ((5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenTemp - 32.0)) + 273.0;
      return kelvin_temp;
   }
   public String toString() {
     String ret_val = "";
     ret_val = String.format("%.1f F, %.1f C, %.1f K",fahrenTemp, getCelsius(), getKelvin());
     return ret_val;
   }
}

We are not allowed to use the Arrays Util

public class Asn5_Test_Temperature
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      Temperature arr_temps [] = 
         {
         new Temperature(90), new Temperature(75), new Temperature(65), new Temperature(95),
         new Temperature(89), new Temperature(67), new Temperature(77), new Temperature(71),
         new Temperature(55), new Temperature(65), new Temperature(64), new Temperature(74),    
         new Temperature(91), new Temperature(86), new Temperature(78), new Temperature(73),    
         new Temperature(68), new Temperature(94), new Temperature(91), new Temperature(62)    
         };

      print_array("After population", arr_temps);
      sort_array(arr_temps);
      print_array("After sort", arr_temps);
      print_days_above_90(arr_temps);
   }
   public static void print_array(String message, Temperature arr_param[])
   {
      System.out.println("----" + message + "---");

      for(Temperature oneElem : arr_param)
         System.out.print(oneElem + "\t");
      System.out.println();
   }
   public static void sort_array(Temperature arr_param[])
   {

      int min;
      int temp = 0;
      for(int i = 0; i < arr_param.length; i++)
      {
         min = i;
         for(int j = i + 1; j < arr_param.length; j++)
         {
            if(arr_param[j] < arr_param[min])
            {
               min = j;
            }
         }
         temp = arr_param[i];
         arr_param[i] = arr_param[min];
         arr_param[min] = temp;
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < arr_param.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.print(arr_param[i] + " ");
      }
   }  
   public static void print_days_above_90(Temperature arr_param[])
   {
      System.out.println("----Days over 90 F---");

         for(int i = 0; i > 90; i++)
         {
            System.out.print(arr_param[i] + " ");
         }
   }
}
```

The program is supposed to print out the array, then in ascending order, then only the ones that are above 90 degrees F

I am having issue getting the sort code to work and getting it to sort the temperatures over 90 degrees F. I get three errors in my code: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<' and error: incompatible types: Temperature cannot be converted to int and error: incompatible types: int cannot be converted to Temperature

Comment: Assuming your Temperature class has getters... you would want to do `if(arr_param[j].getTemperature() < arr_param[min].getTemperature())`

You would need to show what is in your Temperature class for me to be sure

Comment: I have added the Temperature class. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this section call the getFahrenheit method to compare:

```
if(arr_param[j].getFahrenheit() < arr_param[min].getFahrenheit())
{
    min = j;
}
```

For this section.. use the toString method. The purpose of the toString method is to convert your object data to a readable String.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr_param.length; i++)
{
    System.out.print(arr_param[i].toString() + " ");
}
```

I hope this helps and let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: I have added the Temperature class. Thank you for your help!

Comment: I don't see the declaration of your fahrenTemp instance variable but I'll assume it's there and somehow got deleted

Comment: Thank you SO much for your help!! I appreciate your time!

Comment: I still can't get the array to sort in ascending order

Comment: public static void sort_array(Temperature arr_param[]){
     for(int i = 0; i < arr_param.length; i++){
         min = i;
         for(int j = i + 1; j < arr_param.length; j++){
            if(arr_param[j].getFahrenheit() < arr_param[min].getFahrenheit()){
               min = i;
            }
         }
      }
      for(int i = 0; i < arr_param.length; i++)
      {
         System.out.println(arr_param[i] + " ");
      }
   }

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code.. hard to read in a comment